# How to solve duplicate content issues in Magento?

Tags: magento, seo

On magento Site that i am working on certain products have minor changes in the product setup, except the product description.How do i solve the duplicate content issue without creating variable product?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -1):

[Canonicalization](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization) may be your best bet. This tells search engines which version of the page you want to be indexed.

For example:

If you have /productCategory/product001 as well as /newProducts/product001 you would want to add `<link rel=”canonical” href=”http://www.domain.com/productCategory/product001”>` to the new product page to tell search engines to give all ranking authority to the new product page to the actual page for that product.

This product will still rank, you're just going to be showing users the product under its category rather than the product under the new products page.

Comment: Actually those products are in same category, but their names have just minor changes, although  i have already assigned "canonical" to all products.